# Cannot access my Local mysql server from Minikube Cluster

Tags: mysql, minikube

I'm running a service called [Keycloak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keycloak) in [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) for Development purposes and want to connect MySQL Database which is running on my Local Computer.

I am able to access my database by port forwarding local->localhost:3306 with user details but not from minikube.

Using this to my keylock YAML service - `jdbc:mysql://mysqldb/database`

But can't access it from minikube.

I have created one service also for connection.

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysqldb
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysqldb
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: <What should I place here?>
  ports:
  - port: 3306
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~
```

In Ip: I have tried to place my local system IP, localhost, etc. but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

From minikube's documentation:

> To make it easier to access your host, minikube v1.10 adds a hostname
> entry `host.minikube.internal` to `/etc/hosts`. The IP which
> `host.minikube.internal` resolves to is different across drivers, and
> may be different across clusters.

I.e. try `host.minikube.internal` instead of `localhost` and see if that helps.

Reference: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#hostminikubeinternal